# accumulation point of a bounded linear operator

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator acting on a complex Banach space $B.$  Assume that there exists $\epsilon>0$  such that $\lambda I - T$ is one-to-one with a dense image for all $0<|\lambda|<\epsilon.$ In this case, $0$ is not an accumulation point of the spectrum $\sigma(T)?$

Comment: What's the relation between $\epsilon$ and $\lambda$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael  I'm edit my question, thank you. There exists $\epsilon>0$  such that $\lambda I - T$ is one-to-one with a dense image for all $0<|\lambda|<\epsilon.$

Comment: I don't think this is true. If you take an operator whose spectrum is the unit circle, then  for every $0 < |\lambda| < 1/2$, we have that $\lambda I - T$ is invertible. Or any compact set where zero is contained in the interior of the complement of the spectrum.

Comment: @Infimum Sorry my question is the converse. Is $0$ not an accumulation point of the spectrum?

Answer (score 1):

If the range of $\lambda I - T$ is dense but not all of $B$, then $\lambda$ is in the spectrum.

For example, let $T$ be multiplication by the variable $x$ on $L^2[0,1]$.  Then for every $\lambda \in \sigma(T) = [0,1]$, $\lambda I - T$ is one-to-one with dense range.

EDIT: To see that the range is dense, note that the range includes all $L^2$ functions that are $0$ in a neighbourhood of $\lambda$.

Comment: Excuse me, can you please explain here why $\lambda I- T$  has a dense range?

Comment: @pospos, try showing the range is dense in simple functions